# How can I get 2 characters from the middle of a string?

Tags: python, string, character

```py
import time

date = time.strftime("%d:%m:%y")


print date #returns '18:05:14'

print date[-2:] #returns '14'

print date[:2] #returns '18'

#print ??? <-returns '05'
```

How can I (preferably) use the [:*number*:] thing to look for the 4th and 5th character ONLY of "18:05:14" (05)? if i can't use [:#], that's fine. I can't find any possible way, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Specify a start and stop position:

```
>>> date = '18:05:14'
>>> date[3:5]
'05'
>>>
```

`[3:5]` will get every character from index `3` inclusive to index `5` exclusive.

Comment: If you had a longer string and needed some characters near the end, you can go about this counting from the end using negative numbers. ex. `date[-5:-3]` returns `'05'`

Answer (score 1):

You have many ways to get value.

```
print(date[3:5])           # 05 (start the 4th to 5th char)
print(date.split(":")[1])  # 05 (split string and get 2nd string)
```